# Getting width of UISegmentedControl after rotation to landscape

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios

I have a custom UISegmentedControl that I placed using IB into a Navigation bar much like it is done in the iTunes App. When the device is rotated in landscape mode, I want to repopulate the segmented control to make use of the more space I have there.

I do:

`CGFloat controlWidth = self.frame.size.width;`

where self is the custom UISegmentedControl but that always returns 310 as the width.

Now in both code I also set the following resizing mask:

```
self.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
```

which actually makes the segmented control expand properly.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two things that may help:

1. Something about the "top-level" view/container is not "rotated" - thus it's *frame* stays the same - though it's *subviews* are rotated and thus have new frame sizes.
2. Look at the *bounds*, not the *frame*.

I think either one (or both) are pertinent to you.

Answer (score 0):

ok I figured it out. It was neither the top-level view/container or the bounds issues. I was just checking at the wrong time. I had placed the call to check the width inside shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: and of course that only gets called BEFORE the rotation. Duh. I used didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation and that solved it.

Thanks for the suggestions because after trying them out, I noticed that my method was getting called at different times and eventually it worked so I figured it was a timing thing.